# Comparing PHP User input with a mysqli database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, testing

I'm creating an online test. I have the form's and everything set out correctly and it send an email to the admin nicely. However I want it to do this:

I need the script to compare the results with data that is already in the MySQL database, so if question 1 was: "Complete the sentence: We took the dog for a *_*_" and then they answer with "walk", then it will send the answer and weather it is correct in an email like:
1) walk - Correct

Here is the script I have(all the a1,a2, ect... are the answers.):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mywebsite.com","username","password","eiy_testResults");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "ERROR - Failed to connect to MySQL Server. Please contact an administrator: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$emailSubject = 'Online Test results';
$webMaster = 'name@email.com';



$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
// Questions in order. Ad more changing the number (+1).
$a1 = $_POST['a1'];
$a2 = $_POST['a2'];
$a3 = $_POST['a3'];
$a4 = $_POST['a4'];
$a5 = $_POST['a5'];
$a6 = $_POST['a6'];
$a7 = $_POST['a7'];
$a8 = $_POST['a8'];
$a9 = $_POST['a9'];
$a10 = $_POST['a10'];
$a11 = $_POST['a11'];
$a12 = $_POST['a12'];
$a13 = $_POST['a13'];
$a14 = $_POST['a14'];
$a15 = $_POST['a15'];
$a16 = $_POST['a16'];
$a17 = $_POST['a17'];
$a18 = $_POST['a18'];
$a19 = $_POST['a19'];
$a20 = $_POST['a20'];
$a21 = $_POST['a21'];
$a22 = $_POST['a22'];
$a23 = $_POST['a23'];
$a24 = $_POST['a24'];
$a25 = $_POST['a25'];
$a26 = $_POST['a26'];
$a27 = $_POST['a27'];
$a28 = $_POST['a28'];
$a29 = $_POST['a29'];
$a30 = $_POST['a30'];
$a31 = $_POST['a31'];
$a32 = $_POST['a32'];
$a33 = $_POST['a33'];
$a34 = $_POST['a34'];
$a35 = $_POST['a35'];
$a36 = $_POST['a36'];
$a37 = $_POST['a37'];
$a38 = $_POST['a38'];
$a39 = $_POST['a39'];
$a40 = $_POST['a40'];
$a41 = $_POST['a41'];
$a42 = $_POST['a42'];
$a43 = $_POST['a43'];
$a44 = $_POST['a44'];
$a45 = $_POST['a45'];
$a46 = $_POST['a46'];
$a47 = $_POST['a47'];
$a48 = $_POST['a48'];
$a49 = $_POST['a49'];
$a50 = $_POST['a50'];



$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
<strong>Name</strong>: $name <br><br>
<strong>Email</strong>: $email <br><br>
<strong>Date submitted</strong>: $date <br><br>
<strong>Answers</strong>: <br />
$a1, <br />
$a2, <br />
$a3, <br />
$a4, <br />
$a5, <br />
$a6, <br />
$a7, <br />
$a8, <br />
$a9, <br />
$a10, <br />
$a11, <br />
$a12, <br />
$a13, <br />
$a14, <br />
$a15, <br />
$a16, <br />
$a17, <br />
$a18, <br />
$a19, <br />
$a20, <br />
$a21, <br />
$a22, <br />
$a23, <br />
$a24, <br />
$a25, <br />
$a26, <br />
$a27, <br />
$a28, <br />
$a29, <br />
$a30, <br />
$a31, <br />
$a32, <br />
$a33, <br />
$a34, <br />
$a35, <br />
$a36, <br />
$a37, <br />
$a38, <br />
$a39, <br />
$a40, <br />
$a41, <br />
$a42, <br />
$a43, <br />
$a44, <br />
$a45, <br />
$a46, <br />
$a47, <br />
$a48, <br />
$a49, <br />
$a50. <br />
EOD;
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
$success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
$headers);

$theResults = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>English in York | Test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top: 50;"><div class="icon"></div>Thank you for completing the test! <a href="#">Return to the English In York Home Page</a><div class="triangle"></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
EOD;
echo "$theResults";
?>
```

And here is the Test Form page:

```
<!DOCKTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>English in York | Test</title>
        <style>
        .container {
            width: 75%;
            margin: auto auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="testSubmit.php" id="testSubmit">
                <table class="table table-bordered" width="40%">
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Mr John Doe" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="johnjoe@english-in-york.co.uk" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Date:</strong></td>
                        <td><input type="date" name="date" id="date" required></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <h3>PART 1: USE OF ENGLISH</h3>
                <strong>Look at these examples:</strong>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">(i)</td>
                        <td width="75%">My name ________ Nadine.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="Is" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">(ii)</td>
                        <td width="75%">I live _______ York.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="In" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <strong>Now fill in the spaces with ONE word only:</strong>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">1</td>
                        <td width="75%">Where ________ you from?  I'm from York.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a1" id="a1" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">2</td>
                        <td width="75%">What does he _______? He's a doctor.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a2" id="a2" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">3</td>
                        <td width="75%">Is she a student? No, she ________   . She's a teacher.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a3" id="a3" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">4</td>
                        <td width="75%">How ________ is the ticket?  &pound;5.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a4" id="a4" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">5</td>
                        <td width="75%">Do you come from France? No, I ________  . I come from Italy.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a5" id="a5" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">6</td>
                        <td width="75%">________ do you go on holiday? In July.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a6" id="a6" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">7</td>
                        <td width="75%">________ many languages do you speak? Two.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a7" id="a7" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">8</td>
                        <td width="75%">________ is Sarah talking to? Her sister.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a8" id="a8" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">9</td>
                        <td width="75%">Where ________ he work? He works in a bank.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a9" id="a9" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">10</td>
                        <td width="75%">Where's Jane? She ________ watching TV in her room.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a10" id="a10" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right" with="80%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">11</td>
                        <td width="75%">Have you got ________ brothers or sisters?</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a11" id="a11" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">12</td>
                        <td width="75%">What ________ you do yesterday evening? I went to the cinema.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a12" id="a12" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">13</td>
                        <td width="75%">Are they ________ to get married? No, they're not.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a13" id="a13" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">14</td>
                        <td width="75%">Chewing gum ________ invented in Sweden.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a14" id="a14" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">15</td>
                        <td width="75%">This is a lovely house. ________  room is yours?</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a15" id="a15" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">16</td>
                        <td width="75%">I'm not as tall as you, but I'm taller ________ Anna.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a16" id="a16" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">17</td>
                        <td width="75%">How ________ have you known John? Six years.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a17" id="a17" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">18</td>
                        <td width="75%">You ________ get wet if you don't take an umbrella.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a18" id="a18" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">19</td>
                        <td width="75%">Have you ________ met the queen? No, never!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a19" id="a19" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">20</td>
                        <td width="75%">I have been working here ________ 1998.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a20" id="a20" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right" with="80%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">21</td>
                        <td width="75%">How ________ is it from here to the airport? About 5 miles</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a21" id="a21" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">22</td>
                        <td width="75%">This time next week I'll ________ lying on a beach in Spain.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a22" id="a22" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">23</td>
                        <td width="75%">If I knew the answer, I ________ tell you.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a23" id="a23" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">24</td>
                        <td width="75%">I ________ to play tennis when I was young, but now I prefer golf.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a24" id="a24" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">25</td>
                        <td width="75%">When we arrived home, Richard ________ gone to bed.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a25" id="a25" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">26</td>
                        <td width="75%">I've lost my gloves. I ________ have left them on the bus.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a26" id="a26" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">27</td>
                        <td width="75%">We aren't allowed to drink coffee in class... and we _______ chew gum either!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a27" id="a27" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">28</td>
                        <td width="75%">If I ________ gone to the party, I would have met lots of new people.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a28" id="a28" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">29</td>
                        <td width="75%">________ car is this? It's mine.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a29" id="a29" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">30</td>
                        <td width="75%">My house is quite ________ long way from the station.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a30" id="a30" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right" with="80%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">31</td>
                        <td width="75%">I wish somebody ________ answer the phone.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a31" id="a31" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">32</td>
                        <td width="75%">I ________ be driving to the conference... the car’s being serviced.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a32" id="a32" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">33</td>
                        <td width="75%">It was ________ a good book that I couldn’t put it down.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a33" id="a33" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">34</td>
                        <td width="75%">You ________ better take a taxi or you’ll miss the plane.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a34" id="a34" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">35</td>
                        <td width="75%">If ________ I had a new car!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a35" id="a35" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">36</td>
                        <td width="75%">He congratulated her ________ passing the exam.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a36" id="a36" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">37</td>
                        <td width="75%">I'm just like my sister. I take ________ her in every way.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a37" id="a37" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">38</td>
                        <td width="75%">The picnic  ________ to be cancelled yesterday because of the bad weather.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a38" id="a38" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">39</td>
                        <td width="75%">He eats nothing ________ hamburgers!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a39" id="a39" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">40</td>
                        <td width="75%">We ________ have hurried to catch the train - we arrived much too early.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a40" id="a40" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right" with="80%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">41</td>
                        <td width="75%">Stevenson is an architect ________ designs have won international praise.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a41" id="a41" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">42</td>
                        <td width="75%">________ he told you, he was wrong!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a42" id="a42" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">43</td>
                        <td width="75%">On Saturdays, when I was a child, we ________ get up early and go swimming.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a43" id="a43" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">44</td>
                        <td width="75%">I'd ________ stay at home than go to work!</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a44" id="a44" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">45</td>
                        <td width="75%">You can't travel on this train ________ you have a ticket.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a45" id="a45" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">46</td>
                        <td width="75%">I had no ________ lit the barbecue than it started to rain.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a46" id="a46" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">47</td>
                        <td width="75%">Paul was left &pound;40,000 in his father's will, so he set himself ________ as a photographer.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a47" id="a47" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">48</td>
                        <td width="75%">It looks ________ if it's going to rain.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a48" id="a48" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">49</td>
                        <td width="75%">Thank you for your letter, ________ came yesterday.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a49" id="a49" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" style="font-weight:bold;">50</td>
                        <td width="75%">He's the kind of friend who'll stand ________ you through thick and thin.</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="a40" id="a50" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="right" with="80%"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div style="text-align:right;">
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset Test"         class="btn btn-danger"/>
                    <a href="http://www.english-in-york.co.uk" class="btn btn-info">Help</a>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Test" class="btn btn-success"/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <hr />
            &copy; www.english-in-york.co.uk 2013.
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Write select query and compare the result.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm new to MySQL

Comment: use `mysql_fetch_array()` in a while loop and then compare each value on by one and then when you find that write `update` query and update you mysqli database.

Comment: I hope that isn't your true credentials ...

Comment: If you are new to Mysql then learn it first.

Comment: Please supply a bit more information - how do you store your answers?  are they numbered like the questions?  Your table schema would be appreciated.  If you need help with designing the table, please ask.  You would do well to look up for-next loops and perhaps array_flip whilst waiting for an answer.

Comment: They're not my true credentials, no.

Comment: For PHP application of mysqli: http://www.xphp.info/mysqli-tutorial/ For the SQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api.html

Comment: Also, my tables are also numbered the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code stub should do your comparing for you.  I have not tested this code with a database, but from what I can see it ought to work.  It's a bit rough and ready but I've kept it simple so you should be able to follow it:

```
//Set variables to hold output data and total score.

$output="";
$score=0;

//for-next loop.  This means "Set n to value one.  Every time through the loop (between {}) increase n by one.  Do this while n is less than or equal to 50"

for($n=1;$n<=50;$n++)
    {
    $sql="SELECT answer FROM table WHERE answernumber='a$n'";  //sql is specific to your table of course - you will need to change this.
    $result = $con->query($sql); // perform the query
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();  //load the result into the array $row
    $key="a".$n;                     //concatenate to generate the $_POST keys
    if($row['answer']==$_POST[$key]) //compare the data from the table with the answer
        {
        //answer is correct
        $score++;
        $output.="Answer $n is correct</BR>"; //add responses to the output string
        }
        else
        {
        $output.="Answer $n is incorrect</BR>";
        }
    }
$output.="Total score: $score/50";  //add the score
echo $output;  //echo to screen.
```

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example table column for that please?

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b09ba/1 is set up with an example of the sort of thing you might need.

Comment: I did that, and this is returning when I submit the test:
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/flawless/public_html/eiy/testSubmit.php on line 19

Comment: Most likely reason for that is that the sql needs to be changed to reflect your table structure.  If you use the same table that I provided in the fiddle, you will need to change the sql to:  SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE answernumber='a$n'

Answer (score 1):

Beside learning MySQL, try to minimize code using arrays and loops. This is basics for every programmer.